# MongoID InvalidMechanism mongodb_cr

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid

I'm getting the following error when I try to connect to a remote database

```
"mongodb_cr" is invalid, please use mongodb_cr, mongodb_x509, gssapi or plain.
```

I can connect without issue from my terminal or any other app (like robomongo) ussing the same credentials and auth mechanism

What has me puzzled is the `"mongodb_cr" is invalid` please use `mongodb_cr`

Here's the contents of my mongoid.yml file

```
development:
  clients:
    default:
      database: urijijami
      hosts:
        - <%= ENV['MONGO_HOST'] || 'localhost' %>
      options:
        user: <%= ENV['MONGO_USER'] %>
        password: <%= ENV['MONGO_PASS'] %>

        # Change the default authentication mechanism. Valid options are: :scram,
        # :mongodb_cr, :mongodb_x509, and :plain. Note that all authentication
        # mechanisms require username and password, with the exception of :mongodb_x509.
        # Default on mongoDB 3.0 is :scram, default on 2.4 and 2.6 is :plain.
        auth_mech: mongodb_cr

  # Configure Mongoid specific options. (optional)
  options:
    raise_not_found_error: false
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was no MONGO_USER and MONGO_PASS set, so the connection failed because of that. I changed the auth_mech option to

```
<%= 'auth_mech: :mongodb_cr' if ENV['MONGO_USER'].present? %>
```

and it now it works both perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Based on the commented out area this is what the line should read:

```
auth_mech: :mongodb_cr
```